# Typescript: Object with keys' types conditioned by other keys of the same object

Tags: typescript

OK so I have this function that should receive a key and a value from an object. Different keys have different values types associated with them.

I dont want to have a generic function like:

```
function updateField(key: string, value: any) {

}
```

Take for example I have this object here:

```
interface ISessionSpecific {
    students?: number[];
    subject?: number;
    address?: string;
    duration?: string[];
    date?: Date;
}
```

I want to create a function that update a field in this object, but I want it properly types...

so when I call:

```
const value = something;
updateField('address', value);
```

It would throw an error if **value** is not of type **string**;

What I have tried:

```
// First Approach:
type ForField<T extends keyof ISessionSpecific> = {
    field: T;
    value: Required<ISessionSpecific>[T];
};

type Approach1 =
    | ForField<'address'>
    | ForField<'students'>
    | ForField<'date'>
    | ForField<'duration'>
    | ForField<'subject'>;

// Second Approach
type Approach2<T extends ISessionSpecific = ISessionSpecific> = {
    field: keyof T;
    value: T[keyof T];
};

// Testing
const x: [Approach1, Approach2] = [
    { field: 'address', value: 0 }, // Error
    { field: 'address', value: 0 }, // No Error
];
```

My first approach **solves my problem** but I think it is too verbose. Because this interface I created is just an example... the actual interface *might* be much larger.
So I was wondering if there is any way that is more elegant to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) to get type similar to `Approach1` autogenerated:

```
type MapToFieldValue<T, K = keyof T> = K extends keyof T ? { field: K, value: T[K] } : never;

const foo: MapToFieldValue<ISessionSpecific> = { field: 'address', value: 0 } // Expect error;
```

The result of `MapToFieldValue<ISessionSpecific>` will be union equivalent to:

```
type ManualMap = {
    field: "students";
    value: number[] | undefined;
} | {
    field: "subject";
    value: number | undefined;
} | {
    field: "address";
    value: string | undefined;
} | {
    field: "duration";
    value: string[] | undefined;
} | {
    field: 'date';
    value: Date | undefined;
}
```

Another approach using mapped type, produces same result (thanks @Titian):

```
type MapToFieldValue<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { field: K, value: T[K] } }[keyof T]
```

Comment: This also works, simpler to understand IMO: `type MapToFieldValue<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { field: K, value: T[K] } }[keyof T]`

Answer (score 1):

```
interface ISessionSpecific {
    students?: number[];
    subject?: number;
    address?: string;
    duration?: string[];
    date?: Date;
}

function updateField<T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: P, value: T[P]) {
    obj[prop] = value;
}

var myObj: ISessionSpecific = {};


updateField(myObj, "date", new Date()); // OK!
updateField(myObj, "nonExistingProp", "some Value"); // Error "nonExistingProp" is not a valid prop.

let subject1 = 10; // inferred type : number
let subject2 = "10"; // inferred type : string

updateField(myObj, "subject", subject1); // OK!
updateField(myObj, "subject", subject2); // Error Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | undefined'.
updateField(myObj, "subject", undefined); // OK because ISessionSpecific has subject as optional

// if you want the 3rd paramater to be not null or undefined you need to do this:
function updateFieldNotUndefined<T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: P, value:  Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>) {
    obj[prop] = value;
}
updateFieldNotUndefined(myObj, "subject", undefined); // ERROR!


// If you want to pass an object of Key-Value pairs:
function updateFieldKeyValuePair<T, P extends keyof T>(
    obj: T, 
    kvp: { prop: P, value:  Exclude<T[P], null | undefined> }
) {
    obj[kvp.prop] = kvp.value;
}


// if you want to put it in a class:
class SessionSpecific implements ISessionSpecific {
    students?: number[];
    subject?: number;
    address?: string;
    duration?: string[];
    date?: Date;

    public updateField<P extends keyof this>(prop: P, value: this[P]) {
        this[prop] = value;
    }
}
```

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUIGcvAPYjoAOECwMwCyA3gLABQyTyWYArgCYThYD8AXMhBsAtgCNoAbQC6AbgbMWbMQCtSYAUNESo8xszgcOUbH0GsooAOZ7FHNlDhh8ITReszbzDk4iaAIr56AL4MDDBsIAjOBMhsRD6QAGLAEAA2HAA8ACoANMgACsgQAB6QIBxYyADWEACeeDDI2QB8ABR4qoJ5yERQeESCBfkAbnBpbBDdkgXSAJQ0CsydKpJ9A9LIALzIYxMQIWH0Y1DIInUA8l1omDguxKTklNs0wXpH8YkQKekcbedXFT5ABEX2B+RAEAA7shApA2nM5rJkAB6FHIC4AaQAhAxPr4fhl-pdVCCQAQAKIlYCsawFfpEcHIYFYPAiFAANXGk2BSNR6IpUH6p2B5JAVJpzhAVnpA2ByBpQjwYGQcF242AHF6DIAdEc0hAVVhlGpogBGF5mgAMyLRCpAMGgJi1YDqJGQgmE4mgDANRpN6gATC9gdbgbb0aBHUKIC63ShzGBLNKPgkCakiQDSczjap1Ezc6awGa+Xasbj6Pjkhm-lmgTmA9EC42wIHSwKhXhTgBBKBWUTcFWNZCu90Acnc0rHCqq5JVcDuVhAcDEBpHeF6cEc7Mgp2Ho5QY69OmQAB84hUIBRIRwx3rK2nq79iYCQYX8-lIlxr7H2xjMcgEgIHAbBYCgGCmPcJBkBQVAABYLkoebRKqVQDDEy5pEcdrkMgDRsMgUJwOAI5wSgADMUBakQW5wCIvinGAG4SEqKrCGkaTIF2F7fqAsZ4XgBGQvxTHIBwG5gHBNL8OEkTRC4cSPt8NYAHLKgAqpeP5ZD0RSlOUlQ1PUw6tB01w9OsgyFKM3JTEwVIIBMXA5DM0gQmwHFnjxV58RwLQLHQ+hMCsawMpsOx7JMhwPl8hIcGpYCabxN4vtmLItkyX4+Tef4UgASnlFx5RWQA)